# Swift enums needs Int type

Tags: arrays, swift, enums

Why needs the following enum "KW" to be declared as type "Int". Otherwise this code fragment doesn't compile.

```
enum  KW: Int8 {case XXXX=0,NNNR,NRNN,NNNB,NBNN,NRNB,NBNR,NNRB,RBNN,NNNN} //Edge values

struct KSet {
    var normal: [KW]
}

var checkit = [Int8](count:10, repeatedValue: 0)

    func initOne( index: Int8, k: [KW]) {
        checkit[ k[0].rawValue] += 1
        checkit[ k[1].rawValue] += 1
        checkit[ k[2].rawValue] += 1
        checkit[ k[3].rawValue] += 1
    }

initOne(    0, k: [.XXXX, .XXXX, .XXXX, .XXXX]) // one card 4 edges
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't index an array with an `Int8`.  You need to use `Int`.  You can convert the `Int8` to `Int` like this:

```
func initOne( index: Int8, k: [KW]) {
    checkit[ Int(k[0].rawValue)] += 1
    checkit[ Int(k[1].rawValue)] += 1
    checkit[ Int(k[2].rawValue)] += 1
    checkit[ Int(k[3].rawValue)] += 1
}
```

or just make your `enum` use `Int`.